# Build settings in xCode that support iOS 3.0 - 4.0 and iPhone 3g - 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to build an app that is compatible with iPod touches, iPhone 3g, iPhone 4, iOs3.0, etc...
Everytime I build on a 3GS, I use these build settings
Architectures: Standard (armv6 armv7)
Build Active Architecture Only (Unchecked)
Valid architectures (armv6 armv7)
And I select armv7 as the active architecture before I build.

However for 3G, I check the build active architecture only box
and build under armv6.

When I submit to the app store, will it matter what my build settings are for the final build? I noticed that the 3G settings work for the 3GS and 4, along with iOS 4.0. Should I just build active architectures only and select armv6 for the final build before submission?

Edit: Which architecture should I select when building for distribution. armv6 or armv7? Will armv7 still build on iPhone 3G when distributed on the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" for your project. Go to Project -> Edit project settings. Scroll to the "Deployment" section and change "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to iPhone OS 3.0 (or lower if you like).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to read a bit about the Base SDK and Target SDK. It can be a bit confusion, your right. There is a very nice article at: [Developing iPhone Apps with iOS4 SDK, Deploying to 3.x Devices](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html)

You should have no problem in making an app that runs on all the devices you want. I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I understand how to build an app for iOS 3.0 - 4.0. However, my build settings differ when I have to build on an iTouch or 3G as I mentioned above with the active architecture types. My question is whether I used build with Active Architectures Only checked and under armv6, or Uncheck the box and use armv7 which doesn't seem to work for iPhone 3G

Comment: I've also found [Apple's SDK Compatibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html) useful.